# Can anyone help me derive and/or define the infinitesimal generators of a Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, mathematical-physics

I'm doing a project involving Lie groups in Physics, and a part of the project involves generators. I initially used Robert Gilmore's 'Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and some of their Applications'which gives a very detailed account ending with the definition
$$ X_\mu (x') =-\frac{\partial}{\partial q^\mu}(f^j (q^\mu, x'(p)))\bigg|_{q=0} \frac{\partial}{\partial x'^\mu}$$
where X is the infinitesimal generator of a Lie group, with q being some dummy variable, with X going in
$$\delta F = \delta^\mu X_\mu (x') F^S(x'(p)),$$
where $F$ is a transformation in the geometric space. However, according to my thesis supervisor, my explanation inspired by this is not completely correct (for example, it treats a Lie group as its own geometric space, even though the geometric space is a vector space, whereas Lie groups cannot be assumed to be vector spaces). I also tried to instead explain things in terms of Killing vectors, but he noted that Killing vectors are representations of generators, rather than generators themselves, and therefore that this is not entirely correct. Can anyone help me give a better account of what exactly the infinitesimal generators of Lie groups are, and perhaps also direct me to a text that explains this more clearly than Robert Gilmore's textbook?

Comment: Hi, I have edited your post to include the formula. Please check if I am correct. You can edit your post by clicking "Edit".

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of a Lie group as a smooth manifold with a smooth group structure?

Comment: Kajelad, indeed I am. If I understand correctly, because both the Lie group, and the geometric space upon which it acts, are smooth manifolds, they each have a tangent space, which is a vector space. The infinitesimal generators of the Lie group exist in the Lie group's tangent space (close to the identity of the Lie group) and the killing vectors, which are representations of the infinitesimal generators, exist in the tangent space of the geometric space upon which the Lie group acts. Is that correct?

Comment: @Razzmatazz You seem to be talking about the more complicated situation of a Lie group $G$ acting on another smooth manifold $M$. It's simpler to define the Lie algebra (i.e. the infinitesmal generators of $G$) without reference to any such action. The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$ can be defined as a) the tangent space at the identity $T_eG$ or b) the set of left-invariant vector fields on $G$. There is a one-to one correspondence between these, and they are used interchangeably.